# Convert from Unicode Characters to blank in XML File

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

How can i converts specific Unicode Characters From Xml file which is not valid in XML file at the time Desensitization. I just tried to use below Regex Function but not getting Success.

```
string strXML = File.ReadAllText("Xml File Path", Encoding.UTF8);
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex _invalidXMLChars = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<![\uD800-\uDBFF])[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\uFEFF\uFFFE\uFFFF\00EF\00BB\00BF]", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compliled);
strXML = _invalidXMLChars.Replace(strXML, "");
```

[image: Want to discard this Unicode Characters]

Comment: Is your file in fact encoded in UTF8?

Comment: What you see is the BOM (Byte Order Mark) of UTF. How did you manage to put it at the end as it is typically always at the beginning of a UTF encoded file (with BOM)

Comment: @paqogomez its already in encoded Format now. but some times this type of Unicode characters are padding at end of xml file. Now wanted to discard at the time of XML deserlization.

Comment: If the file is indeed UTF-8, then there must already have been some transformation going on before you tried this regex. I mean, that's the text ï»¿ in the file, not a BOM. Solution: simply remove the literal string "ï»¿". Or, find out where it came from and remove it at the source.